# Set from select results constraint

Tags: sql-server

Can I set parameter with more than 1 results from view?

```
Declare @input varchar(1000)
SET @input = (select order from orderlist_view)
```

Error I received is: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: You can't - you can use a table variable or a temp table - depends where you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with `XML`:

```
Declare @input varchar(1000)


select @input = stuff((select distinct ',' + quotename(order)
            from orderlist_view
            for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
```

Would this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a table instead, and do the following task:

```
declare @table table(column_name varchar(1000))
insert @table
select order from orderlist_view
```

-- print the declared table variable

```
select * from @table.
```